# Control variables not significant

Tags: multiple-regression

Study: The impact of satisfaction and loyalty on image

dependent variable: loyalty
independent variables: satisfaction, destination image
control variables: age, sex, nationality, number of visits

I did a multiple regression analysis, both of the independent variables are significant. All of the control variables are not significant. 
What does this mean? And how can i explain this?

The regression analysis without the control variables = R-squared = 60 %
The regression analysis including the control variables = R-squared = 63 %

Comment: The question  needs a revision indicating correct approach used for analysiis.